# Spark hangs/fails on manually starting master node on windows

Tags: windows, apache-spark, windows-7, pyspark

I am trying to manually start a master node on spark (2.1.0) on Windows 7 but the process hangs before it is setup.

```
$ bin\spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
17/05/17 14:23:52 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop 
library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

It gets stuck here indefinitely (more than 10 mins)

My spark installation works fine otherwise, I have used pyspark to write and run scripts locally using pyspark --master local[x]. I am using winutils as this is being ran in standalone mode.

Also I have 2 other machines that I wish to use as workers, these work fine when I run this command on them (setup is near instant) and all environment variables appear to be setup the same on these workers as my (intended) master.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this issue I do not know the cause but a fresh download of spark placed in the same location resolved the problem.